# Use Salesforce to store product Documentation?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, knowledge, html

I have been asked if we can store our documentation as knowledge base articles. This sounds doable if you think of every document page as an individual article.

The problem I see is that, if the documentation needs to have an index and every article(page) needs to be related to another or have previous or next links. I don't see how can you keep that relation after importing the documents as articles.

Our documentation currently looks pretty much like this.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm (index, table of contents, relative links to other pages).

Has anyone worked on something like this or think this can be done using the KB platform?.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi OP i'm starting to research a similar solution, wondering if you were able to accomplish using the Knowledge Base to store and present your product documentation.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't easy but I managed to work around the limitations. There was a lot of custom code involved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't accomplish this using KB Platform only.To structure your documentation like SFDC API doc and have it be served from your Salesforce org will take quite a lot of custom code and even then I am not sure if you can have it the way you want it.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can achieve this with some Vf and Knowledge article from my experience on working on Knowledge .Its basically you will need to arrange in a template and handle through links through href tag.